# Binding Nested-GridView with DataSource DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, binding

I need Binding `Nested-GridView` with `DataSource` using `DataTable` in c#

I need this return e.g.

[image]

My code below tried without success because this is return

[image]

My problem is on `RowDataBound event`

```
protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string customerId = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView gvOrders = ((GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders"));

        gvOrders.DataSource = cgv; // set child datatable to parent gridview as datasource
        gvOrders.DataBind(); // bind the gridview with datasource
    }
}
```

How to do get the value of `gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();` for populate the child table with single CountryCode?

How to do resolve this?

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    DataTable cgv = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Create a datatable as a DataSource of GridViews
            DataTable dtParent = new DataTable(); // parent gridview datasource
            DataTable dtChild = new DataTable(); // child gridview datasource

            dtChild = GetData("SELECT * FROM `countrylanguage` WHERE 1;");
            cgv = dtChild; // set child datatable to temporary datatable

            dtParent = GetData("SELECT * FROM `countrylanguage`;");

            gvCustomers.DataSource = dtParent;
            gvCustomers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gvOrders = ((GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders"));
            gvOrders.DataSource = cgv; // set child datatable to parent gridview as datasource
            gvOrders.DataBind(); // bind the gridview with datasource
        }
    }

    private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


        <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
            DataKeyNames="Language" OnRowDataBound="gvParent_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="IsOfficial" HeaderText="IsOfficial" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Percentage" HeaderText="Percentage" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CountryCode" HeaderText="CountryCode" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Language" HeaderText="Language" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for countrylanguage
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `countrylanguage`;
CREATE TABLE `countrylanguage` (
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Language` char(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IsOfficial` enum('T','F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  `Percentage` float(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CountryCode`,`Language`),
  KEY `CountryCode` (`CountryCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `countryLanguage_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `country` (`Code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of countrylanguage
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('ABW', 'Dutch', 'T', '5.3');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('AFG', 'Balochi', 'F', '0.9');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('AGO', 'Ambo', 'F', '2.4');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('AIA', 'English', 'T', '0.0');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('ALB', 'Albaniana', 'T', '97.9');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('AND', 'Catalan', 'T', '32.3');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('ANT', 'Dutch', 'T', '0.0');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('ARE', 'Arabic', 'T', '42.0');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('ARG', 'Indian Languages', 'F', '0.3');
INSERT INTO `countrylanguage` VALUES ('ARM', 'Azerbaijani', 'F', '2.6');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
    protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string CountryCode = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = ((GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders"));

            cgv.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CountryCode='" + CountryCode.ToString() + "'";
            gvOrders.DataSource = cgv;
            gvOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

[image]